# Does a .DS_Store file contain view settings for its own folder, or does it describe the view(s) of the sub folder(s) contained in its own folder?

Tags: finder, folders

I'm having major issues figuring out how to get my arrange/sort settings to "stick" for my Finder windows—both in Lion, and now in Mountain Lion too (with a completely fresh system).

I created an AppleScript app that sets the size and other view settings for the front Finder window—and I've added it to my Finder toolbar, which makes for a convenient and consistent sizing/positioning of any window with a single click.

The arranging/sorting thing still perplexes me, unfortunately.  I understand the concepts 100% ("arranging" is like a first-level grouping, and "sorting" is second-level sort, applied within each grouping).  What I don't understand is how the heck to get my settings to stick on a per folder basis.  Too often, I'll open my Library folder (for example), only to find that it's no longer arranged and sorted the way I set it up the last time it was open.  The need for constant resorting is so aggravating, and it's made even worse by the lack of available documentation for such a basic function of the most-used app in all of OS X.

I'd love to learn what I'm missing.  In the meantime, I've decided to try to side-step the problem a bit by locking the .DS_Store files for the folders in question so they always maintain the settings I desire.

### My question(s):

Does a .DS_Store file in Directory contain the settings ***for*** `Directory_A`, —or— does it contain the settings for the directories ***within*** Directory_A's sub-directories (e.g., `Directory_B`, `Directory_C` etc.)?  If it's the latter, then I have an additional question: can settings be read/applied recursively down through the directory structure (i.e., can I set up a parent folder the way I want, lock that .DS_Store file, delete all the .DS_Store files from all the directories inside, and then prevent the creation of .DS_Store files from that point forward—thereby ensuring that any folder's view settings will always be derived from that "Master" parent folder?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-J

Comment: According to that anwser https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353481/51903 `.DS_Store` contains view options of subdirectories